# What's the maximum allowable height between a shower drain and the trap?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain, vent, p-trap

Is there a maximum height from my shower drain to the top of the trap (*the length of the tailpipe*)?

I am aware after the trap there must be a 1/4" per ft slope and the vent must be within 60".

**Question:** Can I put my trap 24" below my shower drain?

Comment: Yes, my original question, however, is about how far underneath the shower drain can the P trap be, imagine a vertical pvc pip connecting the drain to the p trap, how tall can this section be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to the International Residential Code, the maximum vertical distance between the sink drain and the entrance to the p-trap is 24 inches.
>
> <sub>[source](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/far-ptrap-below-sink-84460.html#:%7E:text=Maximum%20Distance,p%2Dtrap%20is%2024%20inches)</sub>

Be aware that it'll make a fair bit of noise dropping that far.

Comment: Note that not only will water make noise but I have been in showers where you just hear a general echo and that is with just 12" traps.   I mean it isn't life changing but it is noticeable especially with a few people in a shower.

Comment: Thank you to the both of you!

Comment: Despite the name containing "International", this code seems to be valid only in a very limited number of jurisdictions...